# How to load all files and directory to memory in c++

Tags: c++

I'm doing a program to management of directories and their contents and I want to run a program in determinate directory and load this directory and all the files contained to memory. And return true in case of bee successful.
Example I have a folder that contain 3 files(center.txt, main.csv, re.txt) and 2 folders(1, 2) inside folder 1 is the file(file.txt). I want load this to memory, the files and the directory( and the files that determinate directory contains).
 I want to do I pre-run the directory and while find a file load them to memory.

I have this code to list the files. I want now load to memory

```
void Load(const string &path) {

    DIR *pDIR;
    ifstream inn;
    string   str;
    string c = path;
    const char *f = c.c_str();
    struct dirent *entry;
    if (pDIR = opendir(f)) {
        while (entry = readdir(pDIR)) {
                cout << entry->d_name << "\n";

        }
        closedir(pDIR);
    }
}
```

Comment: And you have tried/ are asking exactly what?

Comment: By consuming the appropriate OS interfaces or libraries. The question is too broad and a bit vague. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help]. Welcome to SO.

Comment: [How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](//stackoverflow.com/q/612097)

Comment: I don´t want a list of files, I want load these files to memory. I want pre-run determinate directory and load the files that directory contains to memory.

Comment: Can't you just `fopen` the files and load the contents manually?

Comment: HolyBlackCat. How can I do that?

Comment: Why someone want to load all files into memory independent of type/content/size? What is the use case of the files in memory? Feels that is an XY-problem!

Answer (score 0):

Piece of code to loop through recursively and load file contents as strings into map. Hope this helps:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, std::string> Load(const std::string& path) {
    // Map with file name and contents
    std::map<std::string, std::string> files;
    DIR* pDIR;
    const char* f = path.c_str();

    pDIR = opendir(f);
    if (!pDIR) {
        return files;
    }

    struct dirent* entry;
    while ((entry = readdir(pDIR))) {
        std::string fileName = std::string(entry->d_name);
        // Skip current dir and parent dir
        if (fileName == "." || fileName == "..") {
            continue;
        }

        // Add current path to the filename
        fileName = path + "/" + fileName;

        // This is directory, load recursively
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            std::cout << "Found directory: " << fileName << std::endl;
            auto ret = Load(fileName);

            // Merge files
            files.insert(ret.begin(), ret.end());
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "Found file: " << fileName << std::endl;

        // Read file contents and add it to map
        std::ifstream file(fileName);
        std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        files[fileName] = content;
    }
    closedir(pDIR);

    return files;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto files = Load(".");
    return 0;
}
```